# Any particular reason there is no custom firmware for the WRT54GC?

Tags: router, firmware

It seems all the other WRT54__ models get the love, why not the WRT54GC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some [sources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WRT54GC#WRT54GC) say that there are other firmwares.

A big problem is flash memory size and RAM size. It has only 1 MiB of flash and that's too small for most GNU/Linux distributions. Same thing for RAM. Take a look at requirements for [DD-WRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD-WRT#Features). It just can't fit nicely in 1 MiB.